# Razor Pages Ignore Routing

Tags: asp.net, razor, routes, razor-pages, conventions

I use Conventions to declare routes in ASP.NET Core 3 like below:

```
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/forms", "{lang}/forms");
}
```

How I can **EXCLUDE** a path from routing? ex. **Javascript** and **Images** folder like what we did in ASP as
`routes.Ignore("{file}.js");`

I spent hours googling but nothing!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?